# begin , end landscape does not rotate pages containing ggplot in R markdown pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, image-rotation

I m able to rotate my pages for my table outputs in pdf generated from r markdown.
but when I want to rotate pages containing ggplot plots it does not work. is there any other way for plots?

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  \usepackage{pdflscape}
  \usepackage{lscape}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```



\begin{landscape}

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds) + geom_point(aes(x=carat, y=price, color=cut)) + geom_smooth(aes(x=carat, y=price, color=cut)) 
```

\end{landscape}
````

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12441594/how-do-i-rotate-a-ggplot-to-landscape?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It appears that knitr or Pandoc doesn't handle the Markdown figure inclusion within the landscape environment.  However, this works for me:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  \usepackage{pdflscape}
  \usepackage{lscape}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\begin{landscape}

This is the image:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds) + geom_point(aes(x=carat, y=price, color=cut)) + geom_smooth(aes(x=carat, y=price, color=cut)) 
```

\includegraphics{Untitled_files/figure-latex/pressure-1.pdf}

Yes, *that* was the image.
\end{landscape}
````

You'll need to change the name of the file to include depending on your own document, and it seems likely other Markdown markup will be ignored in that block, like the italic markers on `*that*`.